# SSRS 2008 CSV Export appending column names to each row

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am trying to export CSV in SSRS 2008. I am getting my data, but on top of that the column names are being appended to the front of each row.

So if my report is this:

```
ColA ColB ColC
1    1    1
2    2    2
3    3    3
```

My CSV Export looks like this:

```
ColA,ColB,ColC,1,1,1
ColA,ColB,ColC,2,2,2
ColA,ColB,ColC,3,3,3
```

Where is this coming from? I have never had this issue in an SSRS report before.I have tried setting some of the output properties for these columns, but when I do that, I lose the entire column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .csv export will include each groups fields with rows underneath. Sounds like you have these labels in a group total row. If the labels are just in headers they shouldn't be included in the data of the report.

One indicator of header rows versus Group total rows are the icons on the left side of the tablix when a cell is selected. Header rows will have a blank gray square. Group Totals will have part of a bracket/parenthesis.